# Вывод динамических столбцов из базы YII2

Tags: yii2, gridview

Есть таблица и связанная таблица в которой хранятся заголовки и значения произвольных полей.

У одного элемнты основной таблицы может быть много дополнительных полей.
Связь по `id` (`tours.id->tourfields.tour_id`). Как в `GridView` их выводить? Название и значение поля в таблице базы. `GridView` выводит только определенное количество столбцов?

При известном количестве и названиях можно и вручную прописать их, а если количество и заголовки заранее неизвестны.

```
GridView::widget([

    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'qadult',
        'qchildren',
        'qbaby',
         //Тут добавить еще произвольное количество столбцов с
        //заголовком и значением из таблицы tourfields.
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы выводились абсолютно все поля таблицы?

Comment: Не все только name,value из связанной таблицы tourfields. name как заголовок столбца и value как значение. Есть таблица в которой туры и таблица с произвольно добавляемыми полями для тура.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если связь в модели называется `tourfields`

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ...
        'tourfields.name',
        'tourfields.value',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Или использовать свои столбцы:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ...
        [
            'header' => 'Tourfields Name',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->tourfields->name;
            }
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Tourfields Value',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->tourfields->value;
            }
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

В [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$columns-detail) так же есть примеры.

Comment: Попробую.  Но кажется это не то. Name должно быть в заголовке столбца, а не там где значение.

Comment: tourfields.name - это название столбца ?

Comment: Да. Должно быть в заголовке таблицы GridView.

Comment: Опишу просто мысли, опробовать в данный момент не могу, выносите `columns` в отдельный массив, выбираете все возможные столбцы (как я понял это возможно), проходитесь по ним и добавляете в массив столбцов, в поле `header` - `tourfields.name`, в `value` можете добавить анонимную функцию или метод модели который бы по какому либо идендификатору доставал для данного столбца значение

Comment: такая же проблема, скажите удалось ли вывести данные как вы хотели, поделитесь пожалуйста